# WPF DataGrid RowValidation Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, row

I have datagrid which has row validation with Virtualization on. I imprted large file with 48 column and 500 rows. It does validation for each visible rows (Virtualization) at the beginning. So if 10 rows are visible to user (it has scroll bar), it validates only 10 rows when data is imported, which is fine.

My Issue is: when I update any cell of datagrid, it does row validation again for 10 rows. I want data grid to validation only that updated row, not all visible rows. My current validation causes performance issue because of that.

Here Is Xaml:

```
               <wpfc4:RhinoDataGrid.RowValidationRules>
                    <wpfc4:CourseValidationRule  ValidationStep="RawProposedValue"/>
                </wpfc4:RhinoDataGrid.RowValidationRules>
```

And Code is:

```
 public class CourseValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        ValidationResult vResult = ValidationResult.ValidResult;
        DataRowView drView = (value as BindingGroup).Items[0] as DataRowView;
        RhinoDataGrid rGrid = VisualTreeHelpers.FindVisualChild<RhinoDataGrid>(Application.Current.MainWindow);
        for (int i = 0; i < drView.Row.ItemArray.Count(); i++)
        {
            string strVal = drView.Row.ItemArray[i].ToString();
            if (strVal.Length > 10)
            {
                vResult = new ValidationResult(false,
                "error.");
                break;
            }
        }
        return vResult;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `ValidationStep` is `UpdatedValue` rather than `RawProposedValue`

```
<wpfc4:RhinoDataGrid.RowValidationRules>
    <wpfc4:CourseValidationRule  ValidationStep="UpdatedValue"/>
</wpfc4:RhinoDataGrid.RowValidationRules>
```

Comment: I Have to use RawProposedValue because I also want to perform validation when data is imported. And only RawProposedValue does validation at that time. once every thing is done and then I changed value of datagrid cell at that time only that row needs to be updated. But in my case it checks for all visible rows even i update only Row 3.